# How to fetch unique field values (song_type) from core data

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, ios4

I would like to know how to fetch unique field values (song_type) from core data.

i have the below code for that

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Songs" inManagedObjectContext:myManagedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    [fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"song_type"]]; 
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSError *aError;

    NSMutableArray *fetchedResultsArray = [[myManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&aError]mutableCopy];

    if(! fetchedResultsArray ){
        NSLog(@"EEEERRROR");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"fetched %d", [fetchedResultsArray count]);
    }

    [fetchedResultsArray release];
    [fetchRequest release];
```

i am getting the below error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid keypath song_type
>   passed to setPropertiesToFetch:'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set following 2 properties and you are done.

```
fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = YES;
fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest= [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Songs" inManagedObjectContext:myManagedObjectContext];

//Take properties dictionary
NSDictionary *entityProperties = [entity propertiesByName];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[fetchRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[entityProperties objectForKey:@"song_type"]]];
NSArray * result = [myManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
```

Comment: i tried but still getting the same errror Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid keypath song_type passed to setPropertiesToFetch:'.pls help

Comment: when i am running like this no error.NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Songs" inManagedObjectContext:myManagedObjectContext]; 
 NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
 [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
 NSError *aError;NSMutableArray *fetchedResultsArray = [[myManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&aError]mutableCopy];
 if(! fetchedResultsArray ){}
 else {
   NSLog(@"fetched %d", [fetchedResultsArray count]);
 }
 [fetchedResultsArray release];
 [fetchRequest release];

Comment: Can you please post Songs Modal class in your question.

Comment: thanks a lot, it works. by the way can you pls explain the code snippet for my understanding please

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13341/discussion-between-user198725878-and-jennis)