# Select specific attribute in entity Core Data

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I'm searching how to select all values for a specific attribute in an entity in Core Data.

Here my model:

I have an entity named "Countries" with 3 attributes of type "String":

- name_en
- name_fr
- name_de

I display the values on a UITableView, but I would like only show the values from name_en OR name_fr OR name_de based on the user default language. At the moment, all the values are selected (name_en, name_fr and name_de).

**The solution (Thanks to Simon):**

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K MATCHES %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name_%@",[Config getCurrentLocale]], @".{1,}"];
```

**Where [Config getCurrentLocale] returns me "fr" OR "de" OR "en".**

Next, apply this predicate to the request:

```
NSFetchRequest * request = [self defaultRequest];

request.predicate = predicate;

self.fetchedResultsController = 
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                    managedObjectContext:context
                                      sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                               cacheName:nil];
```

**========= Relative to my problem (Resolved now) ==========**

Here is my method where I build the fetch request:

```
-(NSFetchRequest *) defaultRequest
{

    NSFetchRequest * request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription * entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:self.entityName
                                            inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];
    NSDictionary *attributes = [entity attributesByName];

    // Put some stuff here to "filter" the request and show only name_en OR name_fr OR name_de ?
    request.entity = entity;
    request.fetchBatchSize = 20;
    //request.fetchLimit = 50;

    request.sortDescriptors = self.defaultSortDescriptors;

    return request;

}
```

Thank you guys for your help.

**EDIT 1**

Here is the data source methods of my subclass of UITableViewController:

```
#pragma mark - UITableView

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsControllerForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
        return self.searchFetchedResultsController;

    if (tableView == self.tableView)
        return self.fetchedResultsController;

    return nil;
}

#pragma mark DataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[[self fetchedResultsControllerForTableView:tableView] sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[[self fetchedResultsControllerForTableView:tableView] sections] objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[[self fetchedResultsControllerForTableView:tableView] sections] objectAtIndex:section] name];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return [[self fetchedResultsControllerForTableView:tableView] sectionForSectionIndexTitle:title atIndex:index];
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self fetchedResultsControllerForTableView:tableView] sectionIndexTitles];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString * identifier = [self cellIdentifierForIndexPath:indexPath];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [self newTableViewCellWithIndentifier:identifier];

    // Configure the cell.
    [self tableView:tableView configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

I try something like this just to show the results in outputs:

```
 NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Countries"];

    fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

    [fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name_en", nil]];

    NSError *error      = nil;
    NSArray *results    = [[AppDelegate sharedInstance].managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    NSMutableArray *countries = [results valueForKey:@"name_en"];

    NSLog(@"Count: %d", countries.count);
```

Normally, I have around 246 countries in name_en, and the count is 757! So, the sum of name_fr + name_en + name_de... I don't understand why :(

Edit => I found a solution here: [How to fetch unique field values (song_type) from core data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306950/how-to-fetch-unique-field-values-song-type-from-core-data)

Now, I have to adapt my code to works with this piece of code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setPropertiesToFetch:
```

Specifies which properties should be returned by the fetch.

```
- (void)setPropertiesToFetch:(NSArray *)values
```

> Parameters
>
> values
>
> An array of `NSPropertyDescription` objects that specify which properties should be returned by the fetch.
>
> Discussion
>
> The property descriptions may represent attributes, to-one relationships, or expressions. The name of an attribute or relationship description must match the name of a description on the fetch request’s entity.

Special Considerations
You must set the entity for the fetch request before setting this value, otherwise `NSFetchRequest` throws an `NSInvalidArgumentException` exception.

This value is only used if resultType is set to `NSDictionaryResultType`.

Availability
Available in iOS 3.0 and later.

Comment: Thank you! I think I've already try, it didn't work. I'll try again and let you know if it works ;)

Comment: Well, it works indeed. But the problem I have is that, in my UITableView, I have all the values from name_fr, name_de and name_nl, BUT the only displayed values are the correct one. I mean, if I set de properties to fetch to "name_en", the values displayed are "name_en" but in my UITableView, I have the number of cells equal to "name_en + name_fr + name_nl values...". I don't understand why :/

Comment: @Lapinou Paste your code on how you implement the UITableViewDatasource Delegate. Didn't get your meaning on your comment-- but in my UITableView, I have the number of cells equal to "name_en + name_fr + name_nl values..."

Comment: @Lapinou Seems like you are going to fetch all Countries that name_en is not null. Then you should append a predicate to the request like this:
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K MATCHES %@", @"name_en", @".{1,}"];
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;